# Ground wire giving shock

Tags: electrical, safety, fire-hazard, diy-vs-pro

All metal appliances in my house give shock. Following is experiment I conducted: I stuck my electrical tester in each hole of my mains wall socket (one by one) and it does not glow on neutral, glows on live, glows very dimly on ground. But when I stuck it with end point of my iPhone charger, it glows (dimly). My iPhone charger has no ground connection (2-pin plug).

[image: iPhone charger giving current]

I also conducted many other experiments but the above experiment is equivalent to all of them. Same thing happens with lenovo charger and my also APC UPS or any other modern appliance. Even if this house does not have ground connected to actual ground, event like this should only happen if all of these appliances have live wire leakage. Is it possible that bodies of electrical appliances gain some voltage when appliance is turned on (without any fault)?

I also tried connecting the ground wire from my UPS to one of metal pipelines (that go beneath my house) and viola! No more electric shocks from my UPS/desktop. While connecting this wire, I noticed my monitor turned off momentarily. Thus, I suspect this might be a huge mistake. Could this cause higher electrical bills?

Any help on what's causing this and how to fix this? This is India, Delhi, BSES yamuna electricity, single phase (domestic).

Comment: It sounds as though you have a broken ground wire to some of the sockets in your house - possibly all of the sockets on at least 1 circuit.

Comment: Please add a country tag to your question. Also describe the way electricity is delivered to your house if you know it -- is it two-phase, three-phase, or split-phase? Is it like in the UK, or the USA, or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be caused by a [bootleg ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootleg_ground) together with a poor neutral connection at the service panel.

> In building wiring, a bootleg ground is an electrical ground that is wired from the neutral side of a receptacle or light fixture in an older 2-wire home. This essentially connects the neutral side of the receptacle to the casing of an appliance or lamp. It can be a hazard because the neutral wire is a current-carrying conductor, which means the casing can become energized.

You have probably encountered the combination of bootleg grounds on some of your receptacles, and a failing neutral path somewhere between the receptacle and the neutral connection from the power utility.

Here are some diagrams that you can show to your local electrician:

---

Home wiring with correct fault grounding: 
[image: correct]
This is the correct way to protect against the appliance case accidentally becoming electrified. If the hot wire (red) insulation fails inside the appliance, the casing will become hot, and almost instantly the circuit breaker will open.

---

Home wiring without fault grounding: 
[image: ungrounded]
The earliest home wiring in my country (USA) didn't have fault grounding, and the appliances of that era didn't have little green ground wires.

Using a modern appliance in such an old house involves living without fault ground protection. As you can see from the diagram, there is obviously no place for the appliance's fault ground connection to go. Most users either use an adapter incorrectly, or break the round ground pin off the plug.

---

Bootleg ground -- what you evidently have: 
[image: bootlegged]
Unscrupulous home sellers and misguided handymen may for various reasons connect the fault ground to the neutral wire inside the receptacle.

Sellers do this because they want to give the *appearance* of fault ground wiring in the house. An untrained repairman may do this because he thinks it is safer than leaving the ground disconnected.

---

Dangerous failure in a bootlegged circuit: 
[image: failed]
In every country, as far as I know, the neutral service connection is held near earth potential by the utility company's wiring, so connecting an appliance's fault ground to the neutral wire *does* provide some protection against an insulation failure inside the appliance.

BUT it introduces a more dangerous and much more common failure mode, the broken neutral. You are much more likely to encounter a corroded or broken neutral wire in an old house than you are to encounter failed insulation in a new appliance. The neutrals are usually clamped to a copper bar in the service panel, and these connections will become corroded over time.

When the neutral path is broken anywhere between the bootleg ground and the service panel, everything that is "grounded" becomes live. You can trace the path in the diagram, from the circuit breaker, thru the hot wire (red), thru the appliance load, down the neutral wire (blue), thru the bootleg connection, and thru the ground wire (green) back to the appliance casing. Because of the high resistance of the failing neutral (probably at the service panel), the appliance casing will be energized and current will flow to nearby earth through any accidental path provided, such as you.

Now, it's true that any current that flows through a person touching an appliance casing must also flow through the appliance loads, which is probably the only reason you are still alive. Note that the more appliances you have running the greater the shock you will get.

---

Connecting a ground wire to the plumbing is a stopgap that may prevent you being electrocuted by touching an appliance, but it introduces a new problem: you can now be electrocuted by touching your plumbing.

You are not going to be able to safely fix this yourself. You must call a licensed professional electrician. Even if you applied some repairs and got rid of the symptoms, without training and experience you might not find all the problems, and would be subjected to dangers later on.

Comment: I updated the question with simplified version of my experiment. Bootleg ground does explain the shocks on 3-pin connector appliances, but it does not explain why my iPhone would give me shocks, because iPhone charger has 2-pin plug (look at updated image). Also, in my country, professional electricians are really dumb. I would need to understand the problem myself and then tell them the solution.

Comment: I don't know -- and I don't want to know -- what is inside an iPhone charger. I will try to improve my answer with a diagram.

Comment: What I wish to understand is this: are circuits designed in a way that the metallic body of an appliance automatically gains electrical potential without any live wire touching it? Because if that is true then I would feel safe connecting it to my underground pipes, as that would not cause my electrical bills to increase.

Comment: It's not just my phone charger, I repeated this exact experiment with my lenovo laptop charger, and exact same result. Same with APC UPS. Somehow the ground connection of these appliances are gaining some voltage once the equipment is turned on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the warning, I did not think about the risk of electrocuting myself by touching faucet. Specially given the fact I would be touching it the next time I am showering. Thanks a bunch there.

Comment: I really appreciate all the explanation and I'll show this to electrician. But I still don't know why the lead of my iPhone charger is giving shock when connected to the mains' socket. It did not give me shock in previous house, and does not give me shock when I connect it to UPS (disconnected from mains). I also tested mains, the neutral from main connection does not turn the tester on, only hot/live does (ignoring ground here because iPhone charger has no ground pin). I know that this place has faulty ground connection. But that is not enough to explain the result of above experiment.

Comment: Please understand that when the building's neutral connection fails, the first thing that happens is the energizing of all the neutral wiring downstream of the failure point. The energizing of some appliance casings via bootleg grounds happens only as a result of the hot neutral. -- Modern phone chargers and similar devices have a switching power supply and do not use a transformer, which means there is a direct connection between the line side neutral and the load side return ground that you have been poking at.

Comment: Does that mean that I have a faulty neutral as well as faulty ground?

Comment: thanks a bunch for explaining. You are right! The neutral here has a failing connection. That is why my iphone gave shocks. And also ground connection is broken, that's why metal bodies give current. Thanks so much for being so patient. I will get both fixed :)

Comment: If my analysis is correct, and it probably is, you don't have a *faulty* ground, you have a *bootleg* ground. But your main problem is that you have a faulty neutral. You can probably find and disconnect all the bootleg grounds yourself, but you will need a licensed electrician and perhaps also the co-operation of the utility company to eliminate the faulty neutral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56277/discussion-between-user49582934-and-a-i-breveleri).

Comment: Try flipping the Apple charger over. (So the pins are reversed).   If it stops doing that, it's a counterfeit.  Apple stuff is built better than that.  @A.I.Breveleri if his neutral is out, how is he getting any power at all?   Most Indian homes only get one leg of hot.

Comment: I was thinking broken ground because it sounded form the OP's original description where plugging in his UPS caused the ground of the whole circuit to become live-ish. The typical Y-capacitors in a UPS's input stage would do that by raising the ground to half supply voltage if it's not really grounded.

Comment: @Harper: Now that I know where the OP is, I think it's more likely that he has a floating neutral than the failing (high-resistance) neutral indicated in my fourth diagram. His power company will have to deal with that.

Comment: @Harper I did try that, reversing pins of apple charger gives identical results.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a downvote on an *accepted* answer before...

Answer (score -1):

Check the bonding screw in the panel. I have found that if it's not bonded correctly it will cause the ground to have voltage leakage on it, which is definitely not safe.